# Is the order of boolean expressions important in while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

what's the different between an expresion like:

```
int a, b;
bool p = false;
while (cin >> a >> b and not p) { // code }

// and:

int a, b;
bool p = false;
while (not p and cin >> a >> b) { // code }
```

Comment: `not` and `and` are more commonly written in C++ as `!` and `&&`, respectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that in C++, a shortcut is followed while evaluating boolean conditions.

In case of an `and`, you know that if the first statement is false, the whole output is false. In this case, the second condition won't be evaluated at all. Similarly, if the first statement in an `or` statement evaluates to true, then the second isn't evaluated.

So why is this useful, except the small effort saved in evaluating the second statement. One of the cases is `AND` is wherein you may not want the second expression to be evaluated if the first one is false. A reason for this is that the second expression may be ill defined if the first statement is false.

For example, when accessing vector elements in a `while` loop, you may have a situation where you are checking some condition. Along with that you'd have to take care to ensure that the index is within the limits of the vector. So you can just write

```
while (i < vector.size() && condition(vector[i]))
```

You can see that if the first part evaluates to `false`, then the program would crash upon accessing `vector[i]` in the condition. However, it doesn't reach that point. This is just one of the many uses of short-circuiting operators.

Comment: `AND` and `OR` aren't C++ keywords. `and` and `or` are.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, i was breaking my head with that

Comment: @Steve : Well pointed out. Personally I never use `and` and `or`. I prefer `&&` and `||`. I wrote them in caps just to point out that they are boolean operators.

Comment: I agree - and the only reason I know `and` and `or` exist is because of this question! (I probably knew it at one time, but never use it, so ...)

Comment: I can give some interesting example of conditions evaluation:

int a = 0;
(++a == 1) && (cout << "a == 1" << endl);

Comment: @PingwinTux What's so interesting about that? It ran exactly as I expected.

Comment: @JorenHeit: Maybe I should give more complex explanation. Short evaluation sometimes may replace simple if statement.It is easy way to use lambda expressions in C++ 0x.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the order is important because of [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

```
while (cin >> a >> b and not p)
```

will take in the input and if that operation succeeds then it will evaluate `p`.  If the input fails then we end the loop and never check `p`.  On the other hand:

```
while (not p and cin >> a >> b)
```

Will evaluate `p` and if `not p` is `false` then the rest of the condition will not be executed.